# Does Hector provide APIs to support composite key?

Tags: cassandra, hector

Right now, I have to manually generate the composite key by formatting the subkeys together. It's ugly and not efficient. I wonder if Hector provides such set of APIs to handle composite keys in a more decent way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it does.

You can look at DynamicCompositeTest for examples:

https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/test/java/me/prettyprint/hector/api/beans/DynamicCompositeTest.java

```
@Test
public void allTypesSerialize() {
    DynamicComposite composite = new DynamicComposite();

    UUID lexUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    com.eaio.uuid.UUID timeUUID = new com.eaio.uuid.UUID();


    //add all forward comparators
    composite.addComponent(0, "AsciiText", AsciiSerializer.get(), "AsciiType", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
    composite.addComponent(1, new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3}, BytesArraySerializer.get(), "BytesType", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
    composite.addComponent(2, -1, IntegerSerializer.get(), "IntegerType", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
    composite.addComponent(3,  lexUUID, UUIDSerializer.get(), "LexicalUUIDType", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
    composite.addComponent(4, -1l, LongSerializer.get(), "LongType", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
    composite.addComponent(5, timeUUID, TimeUUIDSerializer.get(), "TimeUUIDType", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
    composite.addComponent(6, "UTF8Text", StringSerializer.get(), "UTF8Type", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
    composite.addComponent(7,  lexUUID, UUIDSerializer.get(), "UUIDType", ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
```

Comment: thanks! on top of that, what the schema should look like for such column family?

Comment: So since it's called DynamicComposite, there is nothing we can do on schema to "describe" it, is that right?

Comment: Something liek this:
   create column family StateNpaIndexDynamic
        with comparator =         
          'DynamicCompositeType(s=>UTF8Type,l=>LongType)'
           and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
           and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type';