# What should be the connection string while using CQL jdbc driver

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

What should be the connection string while using CQL jdbc driver?

Will I be able to find a proper/complete example for CQL using CQL JDBC driver in Java online?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need the cql jar from the apache site.

Here's the basic test I used after entering data via CLI (using sample from wiki):

```
public class CqlJdbcTestBasic {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra:root/root@localhost:9160/MyKeyspace");

        String query = "SELECT KEY, 'first', last FROM User WHERE age=42";

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next()) {
            System.out.println(result.getString("KEY"));
            System.out.println(result.getString("first"));
            System.out.println(result.getString("last"));
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            con = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The user/password (root/root) seems arbitrary, just be sure to specify the Keyspace (MyKeyspace)

Note, *'first'* is quoted in the query string because it is an CQL keyword

Comment: Hi, libjack That's a great reference. Thank you

Comment: Hi,libjack Does this driver support Composite Keys? I'm getting IndexOutOfBound Exception @ result.next, It works for other standard key formats but.

Comment: Not sure, I mainly use the CQL from within Hector API; and I have not had any problems using Composite Keys there.

Comment: In ur composite keys implementation using hector, Do u delimit the keys with ':' or hector takes care of implementing composite keys? Can I have an example for it?

Comment: Composite is a type (just like Long or String) which has methods to addComponent() and get() values.

Comment: Here's an existing question that has some reference (for DynamicComposite): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440530/does-hector-provide-apis-to-support-composite-key.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the exact link for the jar? I used all the jars in the lib directory of Cassandra distribution (version 1.0.8). `Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");` gives the exception: `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver`.

Comment: Follow up. The jar is not available. We have to d/l the source and build using maven. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try using the cassandra-jdbc driver from http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/.

Alternatively using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```