# Java connect to Cassandra using JDBC [SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Keyspace names must be composed of alphanumerics and underscores]

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra

I have a problem connecting to my Cassandra db using jdbc.

I get as an error message *SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Keyspace names must be composed of alphanumerics and underscores*

This is my jdbc url:
*jdbc:cassandra://test/test@localhost:7199/tutorialspoint*

Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Keyspace names must be composed of alphanumerics and underscores (parsed: 'test@localhost:7199/tutorialspoint')
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:183)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:85)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
This is my method to connect to the db.

```
@Override
public boolean connect() {
    StringBuilder sb_url = new StringBuilder("jdbc:cassandra://")
            .append(this.username)
            .append("/")
            .append(this.password)
            .append("@")
            .append(this.url)
            .append(":")
            .append(this.port)
            .append("/")
            .append(this.database);



    try {
        log.debug("Trying to connect to: {}", sb_url.toString());
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sb_url.toString());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        log.debug("Connection to database could not been established");
        log.debug(ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    log.debug("Connection to database has been established!");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your URL is wrong. I don't use Cassandra my self, but it looks like it should be `jdbc:cassandra:test/test@localhost:7199/tutorialspoint` (note the absence of `//`), see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688571/what-should-be-the-connection-string-while-using-cql-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the connection URL. I replaced

```
 StringBuilder sb_url = new StringBuilder("jdbc:cassandra://")
    .append(this.username)
    .append("/")
    .append(this.password)
    .append("@")
    .append(this.url)
    .append(":")
    .append(this.port)
    .append("/")
    .append(this.database);
```

with:

```
        StringBuilder sb_url = new StringBuilder("jdbc:cassandra://")
            .append(this.url)
            .append(":")
            .append(this.port)
            .append("/")
            .append(this.database)
            ;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", this.username);
    props.setProperty("password", this.password);
```

apparently parsing of the URL

```
jdbc:cassandra://test/test@localhost:7199/tutorialspoint
```

caused an error, because of the '@' in the URL.

I found the solution by inspecting the Cassandra JDBC source code on Github
https://github.com/slowenthal/cassandra-jdbc/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql/jdbc

I hope this helps other people as well. Thanks for you help.

Comment: just as an additional information, _this.url_ is no jdbc url or sth. its the ip address of the server. In my case is tested it with localhost

Answer (score 0):

```
 StringBuilder sb_url = new StringBuilder("jdbc:cassandra://")
        .append(this.username)
        .append("/")
        .append(this.password)
        .append("@")
        .append(this.url)
        .append(":")
        .append(this.port)
        .append("/")
        .append(this.database);
```

This part is really suspicious. `.append(this.url)` Check the url. I think that is again a long string (an actual JDBC URL).

Without looking and surrounding code or debugging, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I am currently not able to post my testing code... i will edit my post on monday. In the testing enviroment i use for the url variable "localhost"